# Unbounded Mapping from $C^{1}([0,1])$ to $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X = C^1([0,1])$ with the norm $||f||_{X} = \max \{ |f(x)| : x \in [0,1] \}$. Let $Y = C([0,1])$ with the norm $||f(x)||_{Y} = \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|dx.$

Prove or disprove that $T: X \rightarrow Y$ defined by $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$ is a bounded mapping.

$\cdot$ I've seen a problem on this site very similar but with both norms being the max norm. I've also seen examples before where the derivative is an unbounded linear mapping. So this makes me think that this mapping is also unbounded, but that's the only intuition I have really.

$\cdot$ So far I've tried coming up with example $f_{n}$ like $x^n$, $x^{\frac{1}{n}+1}$, and so forth, but I don't think any of these work to show unbounded based on my understanding of the problem.

Any ideas or insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f_n(x):=\sin(nx)$.
Then $\|f_n\|_X:=\|f_n\|_\infty \le 1,$
but $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \|T(f)\|_Y=\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n'\|_1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 |n\cos(nx)|\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n |\cos(y)|\,\mathrm dy=\infty.$$

Hence, $T$ is unbounded.